# GeoServer 2.21.1 installation on Windows HTTP 404 error

Tags: geoserver, installation, java, windows, http

I am brand new to the world of servers and am trying to set up an open source solution. When I tried to set-up GeoServer it finished it's installation, but I am getting the dreaded "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found". I am not quite sure where to search to find a solution. I have a feeling I am missing something in my Java set up.

Here is a summary of the steps I followed.

I am working on a Windows OS.

I installed Java 11 through Adoptium (jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot).

I then installed Apache Tomcat 9 using the Full install. After the installation I started the service and opened a web browser to the localhost and received the "If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat"

I then downloaded the GeoServer 2.21.1 win set up package and followed the [installation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/win_installer.html). I pointed the Java runtime environment to the jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot and saw the message "This path is VALID: 64-bit JRE 11 detected". I set my port and chose "Install as a service". I left the installation and data director set to default.

Once installation was complete, I went to the start menu and clicked "Start GeoServer", then checked the service was running, then attempted to connect in the web browser where I received the error. (http://localhost:8080/geoserver)

I've tried looking on the Stack Exchange, Google and YouTube. Most installations seem to be in Ubuntu or Linux so I am having trouble translating the troubleshooting to Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not need Apache Tomcat 9 because GeoServer has the jetty included. I uninstalled Apache Tomcat 9 and the issue was resolved.